# How to extract a list of SNPs from summary data according to p-value in R?

Tags: r, p-value

I have a **GWAS data summary results** that have the following information and want to **extract a list of first 120 SNPs according to p-value in R**. The data have following seven headers:

```
SNPName    n_samplesize    A1Allele    A2Allele    beta     SE      p_value
```

Code via dplyr:

```
    library(dplyr)
    dat <- read.csv(file.choose(MetaAnalysis_Results))
    dat2 <- dat %>% arrange("p_value")
```

The error occurred at sorting

Update:
This worked for me after converting the .csv to .txt file

```
    attach(MetaAnalysis_Results)
    mydata <- MetaAnalysis_Results
    new <- mydata[order(p_value),]
```

Comment: Something like `head(myData[ order(myData$p_value), "SNPName" ], n = 120)`

Comment: @zx8754: This seems to be working but how do I do it if I want SNP list according to lowest to higher p-value?

Comment: You could use tail, or use order with decreasing = TRUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way to do this is to use dplyr. Install it if not existed

```
install.packages("dplyr")

    library(dplyr)
    dat <- read.csv(file.choose())

    #Make sure the data is imported
    head(dat)

    dat <- dat %>% arrange("p_values")
    dat2 <- dat[1:120,]
    write.csv(dat2)
```

Comment: It is a .csv file downloaded directly from the web, and I want to extract a list of first 120 SNPs in a separate file along with other information (seven variables) according to lowest to the higher p-value.

Comment: check the update

Comment: We should order then subset.

Comment: I think he wants to select the first 120 first then subset!

Comment: @Omar113 I want 120 sorted by decreasing to increasing p-value

Comment: can you get clear. Do you want to sort the first 120 occurance or do you want to sort the whole dataset then subset the smallest 120 ?

Comment: Sorry! want to sort the whole dataset and then subset smallest 120.

Comment: The data in total have 2450547 SNPs and I tried to sort and then subset and getting this error: Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : 
  incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : 2450547

Comment: can you edit the post and include the code you have tried?

Comment: @Omar113 I've added the code I used in my original question plz

Comment: I have edited my code. Don't put anything in file.choose() , you will get a pop-up to choose the file from!

Comment: @Omar113: Data imported correctly but giving the same error after the 'arrange' command!

Comment: @Tabbi Can you share the head(dat) output?

Comment: @Omar113 Thank you. I updated my original question earlier as I found the solution